# Compare the cardinality of the following sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Compare the cardinality of
1. $\mathbb{Z}^+$ and $\mathbb{Z}^+\times\mathbb{Z}^+$
2. $\mathbb{Z}^+$ and $(0,1)=\{x\in\mathbb{R} \mid 0<x<1 \}$

My Approach:
1. Using Lexicographic order we can sort $\mathbb{Z}^+ \times \mathbb{Z}^+$, then we can map the $i^{th}$ smallest element in $\mathbb{Z}^+$ to that of $\mathbb{Z}^+ \times \mathbb{Z}^+$. It seems correct to me, but I was wondering is this always the way to prove the cardinality?
2. Both of them are infinite. But I am not able to comment anything about it. But intution says that $(0,1)$ will be bigger as it has infinite bounds i.e there are infinite nos in between $(0.1,0.2)$, where as $\mathbb{Z}^+ $ has 1 bound only i.e $\infty$

Answer (score 1):

For the first part you are right, yes. Giving a bijection between the two sets is the way to go when both are infinite.

For the second part, your intuition is also right, you can not give a bijection in this case, the interval $(0,1)$ is "too big". However, that does not suffice as a proof and it not always works. Take for example the rational numbers. There are infinite many rational numbers between $0.1$ and $0.2$ and any numbers you might give. However, you can still construct a bijection between $\mathbb{Z}^+$ and these numbers. In fact you can even give a bijection between $\mathbb{Z}^+$ and the whole set $\mathbb{Q}$ of rational numbers.

If you haven't heard about countable and uncountable sets, it will be difficult to show that such a bijection can not exist in the second case, so you might want to study a little more about that (or wait until it gets discussed in the lecture).

Comment: Actually I am a final year(IV) B. Tech. student from Electrical Engineering. I am curious in Math and Programming. So have been studying on my own. Thanks for the answer. I will read about it.

Comment: While you talked about the bijection between $\mathbb{Z}^+$ and $\mathbb{Q}$, I guess we can write any rational number of the form $p/q$, so we can associate it with $(p,q)$ and that's already the 1st part of the question asked in this post.

Comment: Yes, well, almost. You have to remember that different pairs can give the same rational number, e.g. $(1,2)$ and $(2,4)$ are both the same number. Thus to construct a bijection you need a little bit more work. The general approach here is to show really generally: If we can give a surjective map, then we can also give a bijection. Counting the pairs will of course give a surjection, and then we are done. If you really want to see the map, there are multiple ways to do it, e.g. by looking at exponents in prime factorizations.

Answer (score 0):

Any $n\in  Z^+$ is the $n$th smallest element of  $Z^+$. But the $n$th smallest  element of $(Z^+)^2$ in the lex.-order is $(1,n).$ Mapping $n$ to the $n$th smallest element of $(Z^+)^2$ maps $n$ to $(1,n),$ so we only get a map from $Z^+$ to $\{1\}\times Z^+.$

For $n\geq 2$ let $S(n)=\{(a,b)\in (Z^+)^2: a+b=n\}.$ There are $n-1$ members of $S(n).$

Partition $Z^+$ into $\{T(n):2\leq n\in Z^+\}$ where each $T(n)$ has $n-1$ members. We have  $T(n)\cap T(m)=\phi$ when $n\ne m$.  And  $\cup_{2\leq n\in Z^+}T(n)=Z^+.$

Let $f$ map each $S(n)$ bijectively to $T(n).$ Then $f:(Z^+)^2\to Z^+$ is a bijection.

For example $T(2)=\{1\},\; T(3)=\{2,3\},\; T(4)=\{4,5,6\},\;T(5)=\{7,8,9,10\},\;$ etc.